# Unused Schengen Visa

Tags: schengen

I got a Schengen visa from the Belgium embassy with a validity of 21 days but for a 7-day stay. I got my passport late from the embassy and my approved leave was over already due to the delay in the application process. My travel dates were from August 6 to August 12, but I got my passport on August 17, with the validity until September 5.

I am unable to travel due to unavoidable circumstances. Will it be a problem for future applications if I don't use this visa? By the way, this is my second Schengen visa. I already used the first one a year and a half ago.

Comment: It will not make future problems. People's plans change; it's not a big deal.

Answer (score 1):

While the officers at next applications may look at former visa and whether you used them, they do understand that plans can change and will most likely completely ignore it.

If being asked about it, you can simply explain the short period in which you could apply and that you could not travel in the window left to you.

Comment: What if I send them a short email now and explain that I cannot travel due to some reasons. Will it be fine ?

Comment: @ArsalanWaleed: They won't care, and will probably be confused about what you want from them.

Comment: @henning . Thanks buddy ,,, So simple thing is to wait till next application and let see what they come up with.