# Renew a German visa without having used the previous visa

Tags: visas, schengen, schengen-visas

I have a valid German visa, which I could not use in the time period allowed. So I will not enter Germany with the current visa. But I need to travel to Germany two weeks after the visa expiry.

Can I get a new visa or extend the current visa? Is there any policy for visa stamping if the previous visa hasn't been used?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to extend a tourist Schengen visa (12 more days)?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/31164/is-it-possible-to-extend-a-tourist-schengen-visa-12-more-days) and [Unused Schengen Visa](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/77569/unused-schengen-visa)