# Unused schengen Visa and reapplication

Tags: visas, schengen

If I have a valid short term Schengen visa and the planned trip is delayed beyond visa validity date, does it have an impact on passport or visa issuance later?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You do not have any legal obligation to use your visa.

You may and likely will be asked why you haven't used previously issued your visa earlier. Simply provide a visa officer with explanations. As long as it is legit, there are no reasons to be stressed about.