# What are the rate of being refused for a schengen visa if I did use my previous visas only one time

Tags: visas, visa-refusals, schengen-visas

I already had 3 schengen visas specifically to France. The first one was a student visa for 1 year. The second one was as tourism visa for 6 months. The last one was for 2 years.

I used the last one and stayed about 6 days in Paris.

I didn't use the student visa as my scholarship has been cancelled. And for second visa, I travelled to Turkey instead.

I applied for a new visa but I am really concerned. The french embassy is rejecting lots of visa applications for several reasons. Even some official employees has been rejected because of the reason #8 saying: documents are not reliable.

I have the same job since my last 2 visas. What are the rate of being refused this time ? Specially if all my documents has been accepted and my application is now at the embassy.

Comment: The consulate does not just randomly refuse visas for no reason. We cannot tell you whether your application will be refused or not. You will simply have to wait.

Comment: That's what I need. No random refusal is the most important.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unused schengen Visa and reapplication](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/95222/unused-schengen-visa-and-reapplication)

Comment: If anything, having unused visas should be positive, it shows that you *were* not desperate to reach the EU to become an illegal immigrant. But of course, your new application will be reviewed using your current situation and the person reviewing it will check that you are still evaluated as posing no (immigration or other) risk, for example "Last time we granted the visa he had a good job and we believed that he would return to his country because of that but now he is jobless and so he has less reasons to return and poses a bigger risk".

Comment: @jpatokal The linked dupe is for unused short stay visa. OP wants to know if unused student visa (D, I presume) will have anegative impact.

Comment: @RedBaron The type of unused visa doesn't really matter.