# Should I cancel my German visa if my research internship has been cancelled?

Tags: schengen-visas, cancellations, work, covid-19

I was scheduled to travel to Germany on a research internship this summer. But due to the spread of COViD-19, my internship has been cancelled. I have however already been issued a visa. Do I need to cancel this visa, or is it okay if I just don’t travel?

Answer (score 7):

It’s ok to just not travel. There’s no need to cancel the visa.

Edit: the answer would be different if you intended to apply for another Schengen visa [Applying for a Schengen Visa even though there's still an existing unused visa](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/8940/applying-for-a-schengen-visa-even-though-theres-still-an-existing-unused-visa)