# Applying for a new Schengen Visa even though there's still an existing used schengen visa

Tags: visas, schengen

My mother had a Schengen visa, which she applied for at the Swiss embassy in India. Validity is for 6 months (01-Mar-2013 to 31-Aug-2013) with a single entry visa, She has already spent 88 days in Switzerland and came back to her home country (India), but wants to apply for another Schengen visa at the Swedish embassy in India; validity would be 90 days from 11-Aug-2013 with a single entry visa.

I've heard it's not possible to apply for a new Schengen visa until the old one expires. Is this true? What are her options?

Comment: When did she enter and when is she planning to come back?

Comment: Related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/8933/can-i-have-multiple-schengen-visas-for-future-travels-in-my-passport

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, what you're heard is correct: you can only stay in the Schengen area for 90 days of any given 180-day period.  It will thus not be possible for your mother to *return* before the 180-day period expires, and note that this period starts from the day she *physically entered* Europe, not when the visa validity started.

That said, she should be able to apply for her new visa before the 180-day period ends, it's only concerned with actually physically entering the country.

See also: [How does the Schengen 90/180 rule work?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13183/about-schengen-90-180-rule)