# Can I have two Schengen visas in one passport?

Tags: visas, schengen, europe, france, germany

I will have to visit Europe twice for five months in total. I am Thai and will need a visa. The maximum stay in europe is 90 days, otherwise you have to apply for a long term stay according to my research. However, it will be complicated and time consuming.

This is my travel plan:

- Aug - Sep: Munich
- Sep - Nov: France (I have to complete a short course in Paris which is not more than 90 days)
- Nov - Dec: Munich again

I am aware that I need to leave and re-enter the country when the duration reaches 90 days. Can I apply for a tourist visa in Germany's embassy for 90 days that's valid in six months and a second visa from France for 90 days. In between these trips, I will leave the continent to Russia or Turkey where a visa is not required and re-enter again.

Therefore I need two Schengen visas but is it possible to have two Schengen visas in one passport?

Comment: Related to [Can I have multiple Schengen visas for future travels in my passport?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/8933/can-i-have-multiple-schengen-visas-for-future-travels-in-my-passport?rq=1)

Comment: I get the feeling that this might be considered as cheating the system, even though you aren't trying to.

Comment: With a short term visa, you are allowed to stay for 90 days within a 180 day period. Leaving the Schengen area after 90 days won't give you the right to immediately reenter and stay for further 90 days. Having multiple overlapping short term visas from different Schengen countries is at least in theory possible, but won't bring you any benefits.

Answer (score 10):

It's possible to have several visas in the same passport (e.g. an expired visa and a new one),  even two unused visas with different periods of validity or back-to-back visas valid over a long period. On the other hand, I don't think consulates would generally issue *overlapping* visas but none of this is relevant to your travel plans.

Whether you have one or several visas and no matter when and where you enter, you can only ever stay [90 days in any 180-day period in the Schengen area](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13183/about-schengen-90-180-rule) using uniform short-stay visas. Having several visas, even several passports, does not open any right to stay longer.

Leaving and re-entering does not make any difference either, *it's not 90 days per entry* or 90 days at once, it's 90 days in any 180-day period.

Based on your plan, what you need is really a long-stay visa, no way around that.