# How soon can I reapply for another Schengen visa after using a granted visa to the Netherlands?

Tags: visas, schengen, netherlands, schengen-visas

I am going to apply for a multiple-entry visa to Netherlands this coming May. If I will be given only a single entry how soon can I apply again for another Schengen visa because I am planning to go to Paris in July too?

Answer (score 4):

You can't have [multiple unused Schengen visas at the same time, but you can apply **immediately after returning** from your Netherlands trip.](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/8933/can-i-have-multiple-schengen-visas-for-future-travels-in-my-passport)

Alternatively, if you can present solid documentation for both the Netherlands and Paris trips, you can try for a multiple-entry visa.  These are usually not granted if it's your first visit to Schengen though.

Comment: Thank you for the response. This helps a lot.but would be possible that they will grant me a single entry visa instead if I will be denied for multiple visa application? Or do I need to reapply again? In addition to this, what should I do to increase my chances of having a multiple Schengen visa since this will be my first time to apply for one? Thanks

Comment: Yes, a multiple entry visa application should be automatically downgraded to a single entry if you qualify for one but not the other.

Comment: Thank you again for your response. One more question, Can the Schengen Visa Application be filled up by hand? It is quiet difficult to edit when you have no PDF Converter.

Comment: The answer you're using to support your answer is not supported by an official source (or any source, for that matter).

Comment: @phoog Pointers to counter-evidence welcome.  But at the end of day, it doesn't make a whole lot of sense to have multiple unused single-entry visas to *any* country, since this is precisely what multiple-entry visas are for!

Comment: @jpatokal suppose the need for the second trip arises before the first trip takes place, but after the visa is issued.  Further suppose that the second trip is proposed 5 days after return from the first.  The consulate considering the second visa application could cancel the first visa and issue a second to cover both trips, or they could issue a second visa. The latter seems simpler and more likely.

Comment: https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/35459/4188 contradicts this answer. It is possible this question should be closed as duplicate of that one.

Answer (score 2):

You could apply immediately after coming back and go back to the Schengen area as soon as you get the visa, there is really no restriction on that. If there is enough time, you could also probably apply before your second trip (consulates usually avoid issuing overlapping Schengen visas but as long as your first visa expires before July, there is nothing stopping another consulate to issue another visa for the second trip, even if you haven't used the first one yet).

But whatever you do, whether you get several visas in short succession or a long validity multiple-entry visa, you cannot stay more than [90 days during any 180-day period](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13183/about-schengen-90-180-rule) on short-stay visas. So if your first stay is too long, you will not be able to get a new visa, making other restrictions unnecessary.

Comment: Couldn't one even seek a visa for the second trip before going on the first trip? For example, one could apply in April for the July trip.

Comment: You can't apply for a visa if one is already issued to you; so you have to travel on it (as it is single use, as per the OP) and then apply for another as upon the return the original is not longer valid.

Comment: @phoog You can probably do that too, yes, maybe I misunderstood the question.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid can you provide a reference to support your assertion? I don't know of anything that would prevent someone who holds a visa valid for a trip in June from being granted in April a visa for a second trip in July. The only thing I know of is that it's not allowed to have two Schengen visas with overlapping periods of validity.

Comment: @phoog I added some remarks about that.