# Apply for new schengen visa with validity date 1 week prior to the start of my existing visa

Tags: visas, schengen, germany, france, multiple-entry

I have an existing multiple entry Schengen visa valid for June 15 to July 14, 2016. It is possible to apply for another/new Schengen visa with validity date starting June 1 to 14 as I need to travel to another Schengen state (France) prior to my current itinerary.

Any advice/input would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/8933/can-i-have-multiple-schengen-visas-for-future-travels-in-my-passport and somewhat contradicting info here: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/28990/can-i-have-two-schengen-visas-in-one-passport

Comment: It's quite an unusual situation but I don't see anything that would forbid it. Do make sure to join a letter explaining your situation very clearly to the application.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is no reason why it would not be possible.

However on the form, there is a specific field to list the visas delivered during the last 3 years (field 26?). Just list your multiple entry visa there: validity date from... to...

The application form is here:[Schengen Visa Application Form](http://www.schengenvisainfo.com/download-schengen-visa-application-form/).

They explicitely expect that people would have already got an issued visa previously (see field #26), they do not mention the validity dates of this previous visa, thus the question falls in this case.

Now it is not possible to give a "proof" that it will work, because the countries reserve for themselves the right to refuse a visa without any reason nor explanation, to whom they want whenever they want... The only way to deal with the problem is just to fill correctly the form, including the mention of a previously issued visa for a later period.

Comment: Welcome to TSE, thanks for your answer. Can you include proof? Or explain how you know. 'No reason why not' is not strong enough proof for me.

Comment: Here is the visa application form : [link](http://www.schengenvisainfo.com/download-schengen-visa-application-form/). The OP should know this form already I think. They explicitely expect that people would have already got an issued visa previously, they do not mention the validity dates of this previous visa, thus he falls exactly in this case.

[TBC].

Comment: You do not need a "proof" to apply, your case is not a weird one. And even if I would know someone who did that and got his 2nd visa, it would not "prove" anything for your case as they have absolutely the right to refuse a visa to whom they want whenever they want.

Comment: Even if I was working at the Foreigh Office/Embassy of a Schengen country and I would tell you that this is perfectly correct, it would still mean nothing for YOU for the same reason. Now what you wanted was an advice and an input, I gave you both, I am fraid that you will never have any "proof".

The fact is : if you don't apply for your visa right now you will not get it in any case.

Comment: And when I answered the comment I did not realize that the one asking for a "proof" was not the OP but a 3rd party person who is not involved... and I can't change my comments now, too late. I apologize to the OP.

Comment: Mike, on TSE we try to get a link and a part of the page into each answer, supporting what people answer, or, if they answer out of personal experience, we like them to mention that.  Can you edit the answer to include the information you have added in the comments?