# Entering with one Schengen visa but exiting with another

Tags: visas, schengen

I have a France-issued Schengen visa until 24/06/2015, and I would like to visit Spain between 21-27/06/2015. When I applied to visa to Spain consulate, they gave me a Schengen visa from 25/06/2015. So I have to enter to Spain with France-issued Schengen visa, and when I will want to leave, I will be used only 3 days from my new visa.

Later in July, I have to go to Germany, I did apply to Spain first because that was my first visit. I will stay in Germany around 10 days. I don't know if these 2 days visit are enough for them to enter Germany with Spain-issued Schengen visa.

It seems that two Schengen visas can not be issued same time. Is that true?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is.

Since Schengen visa allows to travel to any of the Schengen states only 1 visa of any given type can be issued for a given period.

There have been multiple related question on the subject:

- [Can I have multiple Schengen visas for future travels in my passport?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/8933/can-i-have-multiple-schengen-visas-for-future-travels-in-my-passport)

And more specifically:

- [Traveling on back-to-back Schengen visas](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/23350/traveling-on-back-to-back-schengen-visas)

Describing the exact situation you're in having back to back visas and entering on one and leaving on another and possibly from a different country.